# I wanna add number which is correspond to the number of this list's content

Tags: python, django

Now index.html is

```
<html>
　<head>
　<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
　<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.css">
　</head>
　<body>
    <select id="mainDD" data-placeholder="Choose" class="chzn-select" style="width:600px;">
    {% for i in json_data.items.values %}
            <option>{{ i }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <select name="type" id="type1">
    {% for j in json_data.type1.values %}
            <option>{{ j }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <select name="type" id="type2">
    {% for k in json_data.type2.values %}
            <option>{{ k }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <select name="type" id="type3">
    {% for l in json_data.type3.values %}
            <option>{{ l }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <select name="type" id="type4">
    {% for m in json_data.type4.values %}
            <option>{{ m }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>

  <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#mainDD').on('change', function() {
              console.log($(this).val());
              console.log($('#mainDD :selected').text()) ;

              var thisType = "type" + $(this).val();

              for(i=1; i<5; i++) {
                  var thisId = "type" + i;
                  console.log(thisType + " " + thisId);
                  if(thisType !== thisId) {
                    $("#"+thisId).hide();
                  }
                  else {
                    $("#"+thisId).show();
                  }
              }

            }).trigger('change');

        });


  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I wanna add number to  tag like .So my ideal output is

```
<select name="type" id="type1">
      <option value="1">a-1</option>
      <option value="2">a-2</option>
      <option value="3">a-3</option>
      <option value="4">a-4</option>
    </select>
    <select name="type" id="type2">
      <option value="5">b-1</option>
      <option value="6">b-2</option>
      <option value="7">b-3</option>
      <option value="8">b-4</option>
      <option value="9">b-5</option>
    </select>
    <select name="type" id="type3">
      <option value="10">c-1</option>
      <option value="11">c-2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="type" id="type4">
      <option value="12">d-1</option>
      <option value="13">d-2</option>
      <option value="14">d-3</option>
    </select>
```

But now j&k&l&m is read by json file and this jon file maybe is varied the number of contents.For example, now `j` has
`{'type1': [{'---': '---', ‘A’: ‘a’, ‘B’: ‘b’, ‘C: ‘c’, ‘D’: ‘d’}]}` but maybe in the future j has `{'type1': [{'---': '---', ‘A’: ‘a’, ‘B’: ‘b’}]}` or `{'type1': [{'---': '---', ‘A’: ‘a’, ‘B’: ‘b’, ‘C: ‘c’, ‘D’: ‘d’,'E':'e','F','f'}]}` so I wanna show these value by using the number of value, but I cannot understand how I can do it.How should I write it?
views.py is

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from django.shortcuts import render
import json

def index(request):
    with open('./data/data.json', 'r') as f:
        json_data = json.loads(f.read(), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'json_data': json_data})
```

By seeing an answer,I wrote in index.html

```
{% preprocessed = [] %}
{% counter = 0 %}
{% for key in ["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4"]: %}
{% values = [(i + counter, value) for i, value in enumerate(json_data[key].values())] %}
{% preprocessed.append((key, values)) %}
{% counter = len(data[key]) %}
{% for key, values in preprocessed %}
<select name="type" id="{{ key }}">
{% for counter, value in values %}
    <option value="{{ counter }}">{{ value }}-{{counter}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
{% endfor %}
```

TemplateSyntaxError at /app/
Invalid block tag on line 14: 'preprocessed'. Did you forget to register or load this tag? error happens.

Comment: Do the numbers need to correspond to particular data?  If so, you may have a bad time, since json files don't come through in any particular order.

Comment: @TimmSimpkins yes it does.But I did not think so, because I use OrderedDict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need a sequential numbering given that you could probably do something clever with jQuery, but if you want the output like you've shown, you can pre-process your json_data (in views.py):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from django.shortcuts import render
import json

def index(request):
    with open('./data/data.json', 'r') as f:
        json_data = json.loads(f.read(), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
        preprocessed = []
        counter = 0
        for key in ["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4"]:
            values = [(i + counter, value) for i, value in enumerate(json_data[key].values())]
            preprocessed.append((key, values))
            counter = len(data[key])
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'preprocessed': preprocessed})
```

And then pass this in your context (to index.html):

```
{% for key, values in preprocessed %}
    <select name="type" id="{{ key }}">
    {% for counter, value in values %}
        <option value="{{ counter }}">{{ value }}-{{counter}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes,it is my ideal thing.I updated my questions wrote ur codes, but error happens.Do u think I should write ur 1st code in views.py?How can I pass variable of preprocessed&counter in render of views.py?

Comment: Could u write codes by following my views.py codes?

Comment: The top part should go in views.py, not in the template.  I've edited the answer.